# Using customer attribute inside invoice email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, order-email

I have a customer attribute "maconomy" that the user will enter an email address into on signup.

I am trying to Bcc this email address into the invoice emails.

I have successfully hard coded a Bcc in for testing which works great, however I am stuck in trying to retrieve this customer attribute to put into the Bcc!

My code for this sending section is below:

```
public function send()
{
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    // Send all emails from corresponding list
    while (!empty($this->_emailInfos)) {
        $emailInfo = array_pop($this->_emailInfos);
        $erroremails = var_dump($emailInfo);
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        $customerAttr = $customer->getMaconomy();
        // Handle "Bcc" recepients of the current email
        $emailTemplate->addBcc($emailInfo->getBccEmails());
        // Set required design parameters and delegate email sending to Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
        if(!empty($this->_afile))
        {
            $emailTemplate->setEmAttachments($this->_afile); //(by dw)
        }
        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->getStoreId()))->addBCC($customerAttr)
            ->sendTransactional(
                $this->getTemplateId(),
                $this->getSender(),
                $emailInfo->getToEmails(),
                $emailInfo->getToNames(),
                $this->getTemplateParams(),
                $this->getStoreId()
            );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

EDIT: Tried to get the customer ID as below but the log returns a blank variable.

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerId = $customer->getId();
Mage::log($customerId, null, 'mylog.log');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should call the `addBcc` method once, so basically instead of this part of your code:

```
        $customerAttr = $customer->getMaconomy();
        // Handle "Bcc" recepients of the current email
        $emailTemplate->addBcc($emailInfo->getBccEmails());
        // Set required design parameters and delegate email sending to Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
        if(!empty($this->_afile))
        {
            $emailTemplate->setEmAttachments($this->_afile); //(by dw)
        }
        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->getStoreId()))->addBCC($customerAttr)
```

I would try:

```
        $bccs = $emailInfo->getBccEmails();
        $customerAttr = $customer->getMaconomy();
        $bccs[] = $customerAttr;
        // Handle "Bcc" recepients of the current email
        $emailTemplate->addBcc($bccs);
        // Set required design parameters and delegate email sending to Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
        if(!empty($this->_afile))
        {
            $emailTemplate->setEmAttachments($this->_afile); //(by dw)
        }
        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $this->getStoreId()))
```

Comment: Hi thanks this may be better for my Bcc but my issue is that I cannot pull in the "maconomy" customer attribute into the Bcc it returns blank

Comment: Oh yeah ok, where do you defined the `$customerId` variable ?

Comment: I found this in a tutorial for adding one into an email so I haven't actually set it! What is the best way of getting the current customer ID inside this email file?

Comment: So you haven't checked if you are getting a valid customer object? If `$customer->getId()` returns null, then your customer model is not loaded, and of course you cannot get any attributes on it.

Comment: You are correct customer is not an object I just tried and got an error. How can I load the current customers object? I tried the edit above with no luck my log shows an empty variable

Comment: Just to make it clear I am in an order backend and issuing an invoice, I tried using the customer email I have access to to loadbyemail with no luck!